# Codeception fails with Message 'An option named "config" already exists.'

Tags: symfony, codeception

Running Codeception 2.4.5 in a php Webproject on Ubuntu, where codeception is installed via composer

==== Redirecting to Composer-installed version in vendor/codeception ====

I get the Error

```
An option named "config" already exists.
```

While not finding the cause and the reason for this error, my temporary solution was to empty the /vendor/codeception Directory and run

```
composer install
```

This fixed the error. But now I made some changes to my tests, and it reappears.

What can be the reason ?

```
$: which codecept
   /usr/local/bin/codecept
```

Content of codeception.yml

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: ''
            user: ''
            password: ''
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

Content of tests/acceptance.suite.yml

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost/suite/www/'
```

Debug Output (Equal with codecept run, bin/codecept run or vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept run)

```
w@machine:/var/www/_wbs/wbs_suite[master]$ ./vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept run -vvv

In InputDefinition.php line 232:

  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\LogicException]  
  An option named "config" already exists.              


Exception trace:
 Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition->addOption() at /var/www/_wbs/wbs_suite/vendor/symfony/console/Input/InputDefinition.php:222
 Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition->addOptions() at /var/www/_wbs/wbs_suite/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:306
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->mergeApplicationDefinition() at /var/www/_wbs/wbs_suite/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:206
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/_wbs/wbs_suite/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:946
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/_wbs/wbs_suite/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:248
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/_wbs/wbs_suite/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/_wbs/wbs_suite/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Application.php:108
 Codeception\Application->run() at /var/www/_wbs/wbs_suite/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept:42
```

Debug Output in Symfony/Console/Command/Command.php->mergeApplicationDefinition()

```
mergeApplicationDefinitionArray
(
    [help] => Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption Object
        (
            [name:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => help
            [shortcut:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => h
            [mode:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 1
            [default:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 
            [description:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => Display this help message
        )

    [quiet] => Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption Object
        (
            [name:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => quiet
            [shortcut:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => q
            [mode:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 1
            [default:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 
            [description:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => Do not output any message
        )

    [verbose] => Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption Object
        (
            [name:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => verbose
            [shortcut:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => v|vv|vvv
            [mode:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 1
            [default:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 
            [description:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
        )

    [version] => Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption Object
        (
            [name:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => version
            [shortcut:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => V
            [mode:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 1
            [default:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 
            [description:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => Display this application version
        )

    [ansi] => Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption Object
        (
            [name:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => ansi
            [shortcut:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 
            [mode:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 1
            [default:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 
            [description:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => Force ANSI output
        )

    [no-ansi] => Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption Object
        (
            [name:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => no-ansi
            [shortcut:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 
            [mode:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 1
            [default:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 
            [description:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => Disable ANSI output
        )

    [no-interaction] => Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption Object
        (
            [name:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => no-interaction
            [shortcut:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => n
            [mode:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 1
            [default:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 
            [description:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => Do not ask any interactive question
        )

    [config] => Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption Object
        (
            [name:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => config
            [shortcut:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => c
            [mode:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 4
            [default:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => 
            [description:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption:private] => Use custom path for config
        )

)

In InputDefinition.php line 232:

  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\LogicException]  
  An option named "config" already exists.
```

In the codeception Source are several Commands (>10), where the Option 'config' is added to the Command:

```
        new InputOption('config', 'c', InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Use custom path for config')
```

No Idea, where to reset this and how to avoid the double Option ...

Comment: Show content of codeception.yml

Comment: @Naktibalda It is in, In acceptance.suite.yml, I also have a config: . Can this be the reason ?

Comment: Actually it isn't related to `config` section in config files, it looks like an error of symfony/console about --config option. Please run codeception with -vvv flag and see if you get a stacktrace of exception.

Comment: Also stop using globally installed version, run ./vendor/bin/codecept instead.

Comment: Thx, both
 ./vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept run
and 
./bin/codecept run
work.

I am waiting for the error to reappear, could be the solution

Comment: @Naktibalda Debug Output added, No difference in the error with the different calls:

Comment: It looks like a very unique issue. Your options are: a) delete everything and start from scratch b) if first option does not help, do some debugging to discover where these config options are comming from.